# Is the given grammar LALR

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

We are given the following grammar.

*S-->AS/b*

*A-->SA/a*

We have to tell if its LALR or not.

As we all know that LALR is only minimization of CLR, So first I constructed the CLR parsing table using canonical collection of LR(1) items.

In the table there was no conflict.But There is no minimization possible.Does that mean that the given grammar is LALR as there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar is always LALR, if no merging is possible and in this case LALR = CLR, but when merging is possible, we have to see that if conflicts come up and if they do come up, grammar is not LALR and if they don't,the grammar is LALR.